# multiple checkbox to variable

Tags: php, checkbox

hy, i want to ask about multiple Checkbox

this my code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 5 ">
```

and  i want to declare some variable from checkbox

$var1 = [take from 1st checkbox]

$var2 = [take fron 2nd checkbox]

etc

can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was found the answer there is my code.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $check = $_POST['check_list'];
    $var1 = $check[0];
    $var2 = $check[1];
    $var3 = $check[2];
    $var4 = $check[3];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to get the values

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
            echo $check; 
    }
}
?>
```

In your case you can store the value in an array and use it.

> Using [] as in index will cause a sequential numeric array to be
>   created once the data is posted, so sometimes it's better to define
>   your indexes explicitly.

So you can always define your indexes explicitly as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[0]" value="value 1 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[1]" value="value 2 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[2]" value="value 3 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[3]" value="value 4 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[4]" value="value 5 ">
```

And the use the value as:

```
$var=$check_list[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to give them unique names to single them out since unchecked check boxes do not send with typical form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[0]" value="value 1 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[1]" value="value 2 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[2]" value="value 3 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[3]" value="value 4 ">
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[4]" value="value 5 ">
```

And in your php

```
<?php

// Some code to get the 'check_list' parameter and store it in $checkList...

$firstCheckbox = $checkList[0];
$thirdCheckbox = $checkList[2];
```

Comment: what about if my checkbox have a same name?

Comment: Then unless you use the [] syntax, you'll only receive the *last* value sent in that request parameter, it will overwrite the previous parameters using the same name. Using the [] syntax converts the request data to an array and nothing will be overwritten, each value will be added to the array.

Comment: what about if my checkbox have a same name?
or maybe can i give an automatic unique name for my checklist??